# Discovery page - can’t find in search bar but can find in filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have 7.5.0 ELK stack. And see very strange situation. I have index with "message" field and for example this line in it:

```
[comgId:1773182151883136235;expired:false;delivered:true;secured:false;querySecured:true]
```

when I do query "message : 1773182151883136235" it finds nothing (from Discovery page in Kibana)

but if I add filter under the search bar "message is 1773182151883136235" :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "1773182151883136235",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

elastic finds that string. Why???

When inspect both queries I see that search parameters passed in "query" -> "bool" -> "filter": array.
But when I do query in search bar - /index/_search request has :

```
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "match": {
          "message": 1773182151883136300
        }
      }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
```

and find nothing, but with added filter - /index/_search request has:

```
{
  "match_phrase": {
    "message": {
      "query": "1773182151883136235"
    }
  }
},
```

and search succeeded

For users more convenient to write search queries in familiar search bar, instead create filter. Why this happened - is this bug or normal behavior ?

Comment: Please share your mappings

Comment: Here is mapping for message field:

`"message": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have a `message` field in your sample document, I'll just assume we are talking about `comgId`.
2. The new Kibana Query Language (KQL) is a bit pickier about the datatype. Searching for `comgId: 1773182151883136235` doesn't find anything, but changing it to `comgId: "1773182151883136235"` (note the double quotes) works as expected.

PS: Switching to the Lucene query syntax both with and without double quotes works.

Comment: 1. I have "message" field with type "text" and this field has string "[comgId:1773182151883136235;expired:........." , so this string splits by tokens "comgId", "1773182151883136235","expited", ....

2. Yes, you are right double quotes helps and everything finds as expected.

Can you please tell me where to read about this behavior in more detail?

Comment: I'm not sure the docs are perfect for this, but https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.5/kuery-query.html is probably the best starting point; which has a section on quoted strings for phrases but not really the handling of different data types.